# ferromagnetic and Curie temperature. Energy question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

Is energy absorb and release back when a ferromagnetic material heats and cools passing through the Curie temperature?

Comment: this is a 2nd order phase transition and there is heating and cooling involved moving through or just approaching it. This is called the magnetocaloric effect, check gadolinium for room temperature transition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this effect reversible?

Comment: yes it is reversible